# Google Appscript update specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

having a bit of a brain dead moment so have come to StackOverflow for a bit of guidance.

I currently have a script that I use for recording calendar events from a Group Calendar and pulling them into a Google Spreadsheet so I can work some other magic with them.

Currently, it uses:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

And that works perfectly fine, but as I intend on adding more sheets and I only want this one to update / have the data inserted into, I need to change the `.getActiveSheet()` part. I had tried `.getSheetName('name of sheet')`, but this returned problems. Can anyone help me out here? I'm sure it's something simple that I've overlooked. But I just can't put my finger on it!

Many thanks~

Comment: The `getSheetName()` method returns a string, that is the sheet name.  You need to use `getSheetByName(name)`.  Always look at what data type is returned by the method.  You need a *sheet* to be returned, not a string.

Comment: Ahh, good spot. Thanks a ton!

Not that I've gotten any closer to figuring out how to fix the dilemma. But at least I now know why it wasn't working :)

Comment: AHA! Figured it out. Thanks so much for pointing this out to me Sandy, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massive thanks to Sandy for pointing out the blindingly obvious to me!

To reference a certain sheet within your spreadsheet, use the following:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet key")
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reference sheets by the sheet index number:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// or .openById('key');

var sheet = ss.Sheets()[i];    
// i = index number

var name = sheet.getName();
```

This is really helpful in some cases if you have dynamically changing sheet names (e.g. when you insert, duplicate, rename or delete sheets).